# IntelliJ *.gtmpl juzu files

Tags: intellij-idea, platform, juzu

I'm building a Juzu project for portlet development for eXo Platform with IntelliJ.

The problem is that I have template files that are `index.gtmpl`, and I can have HTML coding inside it, but the file opens as a simple text file.

Is there a plugin on a configuration that I'm missing?

Thanks!

================= ** EDIT **  ============================

My file looks like this:

`editMode.gtmpl`

`#{param name=enableComment/}
<form action="@{JuZcretApplication.enableComment()}" method="POST" role="form">
    <h5>Configuration</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" name="enableComment" <%=enableComment ? "checked" : "" %>/>Enable Comment
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate `*.gtmpl` files with the HTML editor:

Open `File > Settings > Editor > File Types > HTML files` and add your extension to registered patterns in the right panel.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Comment: That worked fine for the html, but in the `*.gtmpl` file I have some definitions like `${secret.message}` that aren't accounted for.

Comment: That's because IntelliJ doesn't explicitly support `*.gtmpl` files.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
[**SOLVED**]

I did some further digging in the matter and found a better solution to the issue:

If you associate the `*.gtmpl` file as a `File > Settings > Editor > File Types > Groovy Server Page`.

It's not a complete solution but IntelliJ, as mentioned by @darek-kay, does not support these files.